# How to delete compare and shop by function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, delete, compare, uninstall-module

I'd like to delete all the compare and shop-by functions completely,
how can I do this through the cpanel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't! Not even through the command line.

The Compare function of your Shop is part of the core. If you try to delete that module, your shop won't work anymore. If you just don't want to use the compare functionality, you can disable it with the help of a custom theme.

If you don't have a custom theme yet, follow this guide: [Create a new storefront theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

If you have a theme, you have to add(or if the file already exists, extend it) the following linel to `Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
     </body>
</page>
```

This will remove the compare functionality from the sidebar. To remove it from the product page, add the following lines to `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
     </body>
</page>
```

To remove the compare link from the category view as well, edit the `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file and remove the following lines:

```
<?php if(!$settings['catalog']['compare_button']): ?>
                                    <li><button data-title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       class="action tocompare"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                       role="button">
                                        <i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>
                                    </button></li>
                                <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: And where can I disable this? Thank you

Comment: Sorry @Núria, I was wrong. I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to do it IMO